# Blog: How do we get one of these like the Superusers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

http://blog.superuser.com/

I think we could use a blog too.

**Edit:** I've also seen this: http://blogoverflow.com/ but I'm not sure if this is authorized or not.

Comment: Ask me? Actually I already mentioned it in your chatroom, but go visit the Stack Exchange Blog editor room on chat ;)

Comment: [And here's an actual link to the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs), though I only now see @GAThrawn mentioned exactly the same :-)

Comment: *Cough* http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/837913#837913

Comment: No blog yet :-(

Answer (score 8):

Sure.

There are plenty of great topics for blog posts that can hopefully go far above and beyond being a mere reference answer for common questions

If this gets traction, coordinate with rebecca@stackexchange.com and she can get a provisional blog set up.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure that it's official. See this thread on Android chat last week http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25?m=757179#757179 that links to the Community Blogs chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs

Comment: Do theres two superuser blogs?

Comment: Blog Overflow is the unofficial one and once SE thinks its good enough, it gets made official at blog.x.stackexchange.com, which has so far only happened with SU.

Comment: @Matt Are you still wanting to go through with this?

Answer (score 2):

We now have a set a guidelines for Stack Exchange Community blogs, so make sure you check out [How are blogs created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509) for details on getting one for this community.